# positive linear bijection whose inverse isn't positive

Tags: operator-theory, linear-transformations, positive-definite

Let $f: M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a linear positive map, e.g. $A\geq 0 \implies f(A)\geq 0$. I think I've seen somewhere (although I don't recall where) that it does not have to be the case that when $f$ is a bijection that $f^{-1}$ has to be positive as well. Can somebody give an explicit example of such a map (or a proof that $f^{-1}$ has to be positive as well if I were mistaken).

Comment: By positive do you mean entriwise positive?

Comment: @ZachBoyd: if that were the case, it wouldn't be "operator theory".

Comment: @Zach: Nope, I mean positive semi-definite

Comment: Oops forgot to read the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $T:M_n(\mathbb{C})\rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be $T(X)=X+\frac{1}{2}X^t$.

This map is clearly a linear positive map. Moreover, $T(X)=\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{(X+X^t)}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{(X-X^t)}{2}$.

Note that, $T(S)=\frac{3}{2}S$ and $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}A$, for every symmetric matrix $S$ and for every anti-symmetric matrix $A$.

Thus, $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ are the only eigenvalues of $T$.

So $T$ is a bijection and its inverse is $T^{-1}(X)=\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{(X+X^t)}{2}+2\dfrac{(X-X^t)}{2}=\frac{4}{3}X-\frac{2}{3}X^t$.

Let $v=(1,i)^t$. So $T^{-1}(v\overline{v}^t)=\frac{4}{3}v\overline{v}^t-\frac{2}{3} \overline{v}v^t$.

Note that $(\frac{4}{3}v\overline{v}^t-\frac{2}{3} \overline{v}v^t)\overline{v}=-\frac{4}{3}\overline{v}$.

So $T^{-1}$ is not a positive map.